# Diophantine approximations with the same denominator for a set of numbers

Tags: continued-fractions, diophantine-approximation

This is a general question of ``locating the right field.''  Are there good sources and a fitting name of a research area (and, better yet, results) for the following problem class:

Given a finite set of real numbers $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{K}$, find their rational approximations $n_{1}/d, n_{2}/d, \ldots, n_{K}/d$, that have the same denominator $d$, which is as small as possible (for a given error tolerance).

I have looked at multi-dimensional continued fractions, but that research seems to pursue problems different from the above.

Comment: Believe you want PSLQ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm

Comment: See : Closest vector problem (=nearest lattice point) is trivial for “reduced lattice” ? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62116/closest-vector-problem-nearest-lattice-point-is-trivial-for-reduced-lattice

Comment: You have a vector $x$ and you want to find the nearest lattice point created by a $1/d$ lattice in $K$ dimensions. Not exactly the problem described but the field of such problems.

Comment: @arthur Actually, that is pretty much the problem, I just have an additional constraint: one on the value of $d$.  Thanks!

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~Doug.Hensley/SimultaneousDiophantine.pdf

Comment: @O.S.Dawg, thanks, I'll take a look!

Comment: Here is a good bibliography on similar problems: http://keithbriggs.info/dioph-bib.html